# Why are my vertex points not wrapped on my object?

Tags: modeling, vertices, mirror

So I'm following this tutorial and whenever they move vertex points it is perfectly wrapped on the object, however mine are like floating above.

[image]

[image]

The tutorial object

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just click on this symbol here on your subdivision modifier: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just realized this! thanks

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @makerbaker so are you going to show your appreciation for the answer with an acceptance checkmark?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

By default, modifiers show you the "real", original state of the mesh. You can enable *On Cage* view by clicking its button in the modifier window, along with other display options:

[image]